# Cloudformation AWS: Connect RDS to subnets

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to build a cloudformation template but I have some trouble with how to connect my Oracle RDS instance with my two subnets.
My parameters are :

```
"3DCFDB": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
            "AllocatedStorage": "20",
            "Engine": "oracle-se2",
            "EngineVersion": "12.1.0.2.v13",
            "MasterUsername": {
                "Ref": "user"
            },
            "MasterUserPassword": {
                "Ref": "password"
            }
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "*"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "3DEXPSUBPU",
            "3DSUBPRI"
        ]
    }
```

What parameter am I supposed to add to connect my RDS to 2 subnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to create a resource with Type `"Type": AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup`, then inside your `"Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"` you can refer to the subnet group with something similar to this

```
"3DCFDB": {
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
    "Properties": {
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
        "AllocatedStorage": "20",
        "Engine": "oracle-se2",
        "EngineVersion": "12.1.0.2.v13",
        "DBSubnetGroupName": {
           "Ref": "DBsubnetGroup"
        }
        "MasterUsername": {
            "Ref": "user"
        },
        "MasterUserPassword": {
            "Ref": "password"
        }
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "id": "*"
        }
    },
    "DependsOn": [
        "3DEXPSUBPU",
        "3DSUBPRI"
    ]
},
"DBsubnetGroup": {
 "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
 ...
 ...
 }
```

More info can be found here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbsubnet-group.html